# How to Find Exact Path of File on Webserver

Tags: networking, webserver

Is it possible to know the Exact Path of the File on the Server. For example this URL  `http://www.hdfcsec.com/Research/ResearchDetails.aspx?report_id=2987918` resolves to a PDF. How to determine the direct location to the PDF file ? Any tools like network connection traces or pointers to find the same is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Short of examining the actual source of `ResearchDetails.aspx` and figuring out where it takes its file from, no. Server-side scripts (and non-script binaries) can handle the request in any way they need and produce any data. There are cases where PDFs are dynamically generated by scripts and do not exist as actual files at all.

Comment: I was wondering if their are any tools like network monitoring etc which can show the exact locations the machine is connected to while downloading and thus that way we can figure out.

Comment: If `ResearchDetails.aspx` _redirects_ to the PDF resource, you can see that in network inspectors (e.g. the Webkit Developer Tools, or Firebug in Firefox, etc). However if that `aspx` actually _outputs_ the PDF resource, the original location of the PDF will not be visible over the network at all.